# Get list of attributes of an object in an List

Tags: java, class, list, collections

When there is an `List<Person>`, is there a possibility of getting List of all `person.getName()` out of that?
Is there an prepared call for that, or do I have to write an foreach loop like:

```
List<Person> personList = new ArrayList<Person>();
List<String> namesList = new ArrayList<String>();
for(Person person : personList){
    namesList.add(personList.getName());
}
```

Answer (score 139, accepted):

**Java 8 and above:**

```
List<String> namesList = personList.stream()
                                   .map(Person::getName)
                                   .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

If you need to make sure you get an `ArrayList` as a result, you have to change the last line to:

```
                                    ...
                                    .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
```

---

**Java 7 and below:**

The standard collection API prior to Java 8 has no support for such transformation. You'll have to write a loop (or wrap it in some "map" function of your own), unless you turn to some fancier collection API / extension.

(The lines in your Java snippet are exactly the lines I would use.)

In Apache Commons, you could use [`CollectionUtils.collect`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/CollectionUtils.html#collect(java.lang.Iterable,%20org.apache.commons.collections4.Transformer)) and a [`Transformer`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/Transformer.html)

In Guava, you could use the [`Lists.transform`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Lists.html#transform(java.util.List,%20com.google.common.base.Function)) method.

Comment: I am not impressed by the increase in readability. It's less verbose though. We did get 50% less characters. "Yeah" I guess ? How is it performance wise ?

Comment: Neither am I. TBH I rarely think the stream API improves readability.

Answer (score 17):

You might have done this but for others

using Java 1.8

```
List<String> namesList = personList.stream().map(p -> p.getName()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 6):

Try this

```
Collection<String> names = CollectionUtils.collect(personList, TransformerUtils.invokerTransformer("getName"));
```

Use apache commons collection api.

Answer (score 3):

I think you will always need to do that. But if you will always need such things, then I would suggest to make another class, for example call it `People` where `personList` is a variable.

Something like this:

```
class People{
    List<Person> personList;
    //Getters and Setters

    //Special getters
    public List<string> getPeopleNames(){
         //implement your method here        
    }

    public List<Long> getPeopleAges(){
         //get all people ages here
    }
}
```

In this case you will need to call one getter only each time.

Answer (score 2):

Not tested but this is the idea:

```
public static <T, Q> List<T> getAttributeList(List list, Class<? extends Q> clazz, String  attribute)    
{
    List<T> attrList= new ArrayList<T>();

    attribute = attribute.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + attribute.substring(1); 
    String methodName = "get"+attribute;

    for(Object obj: personList){
        T aux = (T)clazz.getDeclaredMethod(methodName, new Class[0]).invoke(obj, new Object[0]);
        attrList.add(aux);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

take a look at http://code.google.com/p/lambdaj/ - there is LINQ equivalent for Java. Using it won't avoid iterating all over items but the code would be more compressed.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to loop through and access each objects `getName()`.

Maybe [guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Function.html) can do something fancy ...

Comment: Can you provide an example with guava?

Answer (score 0):

There is no other way to do this in Java than the one you suggested, at least as long as you are sticking with the standard Java Collection API.

I have been wishing for something like this for a long time... Especially since I tasted the sweet freedom of Ruby, which has wonderful things like collect and select working with closures.