# Optimized method of getting list of attributes in Java 8?

Tags: java, list, design-patterns, java-8, java-stream

My question is an extension of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7309259/get-list-of-attributes-of-an-object-in-an-list).

To get a list of attributes we can use this code:

```
List<String> namesList = personList.stream()
                                   .map(Person::getName)
                                   .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

However if I want to get 100 different attributes.

***Option #1:***

```
List<Integer> ageList = personList.stream()
                                   .map(Person::getAge)
                                   .collect(Collectors.toList());

List<String> surnamesList = personList.stream()
                                   .map(Person::getSurname)
                                   .collect(Collectors.toList());

List<String> fathersNamesList = personList.stream()
                                   .map(Person::getFathersName)
                                   .collect(Collectors.toList());

List<String> mothersNamesList = personList.stream()
                                   .map(Person::getMothersName)
                                   .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

then would it be better to rewrite this line 100 times or should I simply run 1 loop and collect all the attributes there.

***Option #2:***

```
for(Person person : persons) {
    namesList.add(person.getName());
    surnamesList.add(person.getSurname());
    fathersNamesList.add(person.getFathersName());
    ...
}
```

Comment: Do you want separate lists for each type of name, or a single combined list with all of them mixed together?

Comment: @JohnKugelman: separate lists

Comment: Why use streams? Why not a simple for loop? It would be faster too.

Comment: Frame challenge: Why are you splitting the attributes into 100 separate lists? You probably shouldn't be doing that in the first place. It sounds like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). If you tell us what your end goal is we can probably suggest a better approach than creating 100 lists.

Answer (score 3):

Just use a loop:

```
// Allocate correct size to avoid resizing
List<String> names = new ArrayList<>(persons.size());
List<String> surnames = new ArrayList<>(persons.size());
List<String> ages = new ArrayList<>(persons.size());
// etc

for (Person person : persons) {
    names.add(person.getName);
    surnames.add(person.getSurname);
    ages.add(person.getAge);
    // etc
}
```

This will out-perform using streams by a very large margin, and it's easy to read and understand.

---

Minor note: Avoid including the type of a variable in its name, ie prefer `names` over `namesList`. [Hungarian notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation) in any form is an anti-pattern.

Answer (score 2):

Duplicating the same logic isn't an option.

For that purpose it's way better to create a generic method that takes two arguments a **source list** and a **function**:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> ageList = getListOfAttributes(personList, Person::getAge);
        List<String> surnamesList = getListOfAttributes(personList, Person::getSurName);
    }
```

```
    public static <T, R> List<R> getListOfAttributes(List<T> source,
                                                     Function<T, R> func) {
        return source.stream()
                .map(func)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
```

Comment: Yes. But is it more efficient?

It appears that I am running 100 loops or 100 streams here.

Otherwise I can do this, with just one loop.

Comment: @FarrukhChishti I didn't assume that in your domain you need all 100 list at once, as thought you mean there could be 100 (many) different attributes. Well, seems like we  need another approach

Comment: @FarrukhChishti What do kind of type do you expect as a result?

Comment: @FarrukhChishti If it will be possible to come up with an aggregate uniform type for all these lists then it'll be possible to iterate over the source only ones applying a bunch of functions at each step. But with the current description of the problem, it's not doable, there is no uniform type in between the String and Integer (Object isn't taken into account - there is nothing helpful can be done with it). 100 lists that are clattering the code and memory just in order to duplicate the information that is easily accessible - that doesn't seem to be a good idea.

Comment: @FarrukhChishti The task look's rather theoretical, you have to think about the use-case for this data

Comment: I guess all possible solutions have been named. You can calculate all at once, which is more  cpu-efficient if all the data is actually used. You can calculate, on demand, which is less cpu-efficient. And both solutions can be done with storing the result or recalculating every time it is requested.... which shifts the load from cpu to memory or vice versa.

I guess an on-demand calculation is a good approach if it is unclear if you actually need all the data. The "load it all at once" approach makes more sense if you know that the data will be needed.

Answer (score 1):

With Streams, a solution that is closer to the loop approach is to create a custom aggregate type:

```
class AggregatedPersonDetails {
    List<Integer> ageList = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> surnamesList = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> fathersnamesList = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> mothersnamesList = new ArrayList<>();

    public void add(Person person) {
        ageList.add(person.getAge());
        surnamesList.add(person.getSurName());
        fathersnamesList.add(person.getFathersName());
        mothersnamesList.add(person.getMothersName());
    }

    public AggregatedPersonDetails merge(AggregatedPersonDetails other) {
        ageList.addAll(other.ageList);
        surnamesList.addAll(other.surnamesList);
        fathersnamesList.addAll(other.fathersnamesList);
        mothersnamesList.addAll(other.mothersnamesList);
        return this;
    }
}
```

which you would use as:

```
AggregatedPersonDetails aggregatedDetails = personList.stream().collect(
        AggregatedPersonDetails::new,
        AggregatedPersonDetails::add,
        AggregatedPersonDetails::merge);
```

This allows to do just one iteration.

If you need to do this at multiple places, you can extract a reusable `Collector` from it:

```
Collector<Person, AggregatedPersonDetails, AggregatedPersonDetails> collector =
        Collector.of(AggregatedPersonDetails::new, AggregatedPersonDetails::add, AggregatedPersonDetails::merge);
```

(otherwise you can change the `merge()` method to return `void`)